# Powerbuilder Datawindow Crosstab Display

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I have 20 columns and 1 row in my crosstab where display in portrait 8" x 13", now when I print out the first 14th columns is display in the first line of page 1 then the next 14th above columns is display in the first line of the next page.
       Any idea how I can display the exceeded 14th above columns continue on the next line below the first 14 columns of the crosstab.

Any idea well appreciate.

this is the my datawindow crosstab source code:

```
release 10.5;
datawindow(units=0 timer_interval=0 color=1073741824 processing=4 HTMLDW=no  
print.printername="" print.documentname="" print.orientation = 0 print.margin.left 
= 110  print.margin.right = 110 print.margin.top = 96 print.margin.bottom = 96  
print.paper.source = 0 print.paper.size = 0 print.canusedefaultprinter=yes  
print.prompt=no print.buttons=no print.preview.buttons=no print.cliptext=no 
print.overrideprintjob=no print.collate=yes print.preview.outline=yes hidegrayline=no  
crosstab.dynamic = yes grid.lines=1 grid.columnmove=no selected.mouse=no )
header[1](height=0 color="536870912" )
header[2](height=132 color="536870912" )
summary(height=0 color="536870912" )
footer(height=0 color="536870912" )
detail(height=60 color="536870912" )
table(column=(type=char(20) updatewhereclause=yes name=substr dbname="substr" )
column=(type=char(20) updatewhereclause=yes name=val dbname="val" )
retrieve="PBSELECT( VERSION(400) TABLE(NAME=~"public.product~" )        
TABLE(NAME=~"public.product_parts~" ) COLUMN(NAME=~"public.product_parts.part_name~")  
COLUMN(NAME=~"public.product_parts.part_no~")            COMPUTE(NAME=~"SUBSTR(public.product.codeno,LENGTH(public.product.codeno),LENGTH(public.pro    duct.codeno))~") COMPUTE(NAME=~"'' as itemhead~") COMPUTE(NAME=~"'' as imagepath~")    
JOIN (LEFT=~"public.product.codeno~"    OP =~"=~"RIGHT=~"public.product_parts.codeno~" 
)WHERE(    EXP1 =~"public.product_parts.codeno~"   OP =~"like~"    EXP2 =~":codeno~" ) 
) ARG(NAME = ~"codeno~" TYPE = string) " arguments=(("codeno", string))  sort="substr  
A " )
text(band=header[2] alignment="0" text="@product_parts_part_no" border="0" color="0"   
x="146" y="68" height="52" width="137" html.valueishtml="0"  name=val_t visible="1"   
font.face="Tahoma" font.height="-8" font.weight="700"  font.family="2" font.pitch="2"  
font.charset="0" background.mode="1" background.color="536870912" )
column(band=detail id=1 alignment="0" tabsequence=32766 border="0" color="33554432"  
x="9" y="4" height="76" width="128" format="[general]" html.valueishtml="0"  
name=substr visible="1" edit.limit=0 edit.case=any edit.focusrectangle=no 
edit.autoselect=no edit.autohscroll=yes  font.face="Tahoma" font.height="-9"  
font.weight="700"  font.family="2" font.pitch="2" font.charset="0" background.mode="1" 
background.color="536870912" )
column(band=detail id=2 alignment="0" tabsequence=32766 border="0" color="33554432"  
x="146" y="0" height="76" width="137" format="[general]" html.valueishtml="0"   
name=val visible="1" edit.limit=0 edit.case=any edit.focusrectangle=no  
edit.autoselect=no edit.autohscroll=yes crosstab.repeat=yes  font.face="Courier New" 
font.height="-10" font.weight="400"  font.family="1" font.pitch="1" font.charset="0" 
background.mode="1" background.color="536870912" )
crosstab(band = foreground  crosstabonly = yes 
columns = "product_parts_part_no" rows = "substr" values = "case ( 
product_parts_part_no  when  product_parts_part_no  then  product_parts_part_name  )" 
sourcenames = "product_parts_part_name, product_parts_part_no, substr, itemhead, 
imagepath")htmltable(border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" )
htmlgen(clientevents="1" clientvalidation="1" clientcomputedfields="1" 
clientformatting="0" clientscriptable="0" generatejavascript="1" 
encodeselflinkargs="1" netscapelayers="0" pagingmethod=0 generatedddwframes="1" )
xhtmlgen() cssgen(sessionspecific="0" )
xmlgen(inline="0" )
xsltgen()
jsgen()
export.xml(headgroups="1" includewhitespace="0" metadatatype=0 savemetadata=0 )
import.xml()
export.pdf(method=0 distill.custompostscript="0" xslfop.print="0" )
export.xhtml()
```

**Desired Output in my Datawindow Crosstab:**

```
  1    2     3     4      5     6      7   8    9    10    11   12     13    14
A MGY  RBLS WISHI. MILES  AND  MILES   CX  FF  RVS   PCS   ADM  DROP   NOT   CS
  15   16    17    18     19    20
  PHIL AUS  GER    FRA    BULL 1.5oX
```

Thanks,
Jhon Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a Tabular DataWindow with the columns arranged the way you want and copy the data into it from the Crosstab.

Comment: how copy data from tablular to crosstab